# which one is more efficient for comparing two strings?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want it to know which one of this two options it will be faster and more efficient:
This:

```
if(str === 'javascript') {
    alert("good");
}
```

or:

```
var regexp = /^(:?hola)&/;
if(regexp.test(str)) {
    alert("good");
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Go here: http://jsperf.com, run a test, then come back and tell us which is faster :)

Comment: The question should be "Which approach is more *appropriate* for comparing two strings?" (But I don't think that needs an SO question.)

Comment: If you want to define a non-capturing group you should be using `(?:hola)`. Your expression `(:?hola)&` will either match `hola` or `:hola` and put it in group 1. You usually use regex for advanced string matching/replacing. Any simple string comparison should be done with native code (no regex).

Answer (score 2):

Directly comparing two strings will certainly be faster than a regular expression. This is most likely true for any language.